# I don't understand what the usage of "still" in this sentence is meant to convey

Tags: word-usage

I found a sentence contructed this way,

> Even John Doe, the best athlete in that country, a sportsman not only great at athletics but also an expert martial artist, ***still had to give up on*** bouldering, because it required a completely different type strength and technique.

where I have no clue as to why the part I highlighted in bold is written as it is.

Given the fact that somebody is not good at activity "A" even if they are good at other activities that would make one thing he's good at "A", I would have expected that the highlighted text be *"gave up on"* or *"had to give up on"* rather than *"**still** had to give up on"*.

*"**still** had to give up on* makes me think that he had not given up **yet**, which doesn't seem a human reaction that would support the claim that activity "A" (bouldering in the example) is more difficult than the others.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the use of *still*?

Comment: In this context, ***still*** is just another "intensifier" providing further emphasis to initial ***even*** (*both* of which are entirely optional, here). It's got nothing to do with the passage of time or whether anything has ***yet*** happened. Compare ***actually***, often used in the same context with the same "intensifier" meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Despite** John Doe **being** the best athlete in the country, he had to give up on bouldering.

> still adverb (DESPITE)
>
> despite that:
>
> You may not approve of what he did, but he's still your brother.
>
> I know you don't like her, but you still don't have to be so rude to
> her.
>
> Even though she doesn't really have the time, she still offered to
> help.

[Still (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/still)